Create Threaded Comment in VBA within Workbook 1 but post the comment in Workbook 2 in a cell based on an Index and Match result
Can anyone point me in the right direction with this code? I am working on an exam tracker where the user can enter the information for an exam or mock exam into set cells in workbook 1 and some VBA code will create a Threaded Comment to paste into that learners relevant cell on Workbook 2.
Each learner has a unique learning number which I am hoping to use as an Index Match to put the comment in the correct cell.
Worksheet 1 where data is entered. 
I have put the SearchValue in cell A1 for now. This is the value that I am looking to search in the index match within workbook 2.
workbook 2 has multiple sheets, so I want it to "error and check next" until it finds the match, then paste the comment in the relevant indexed cell.
Workbook 2 where the comment needs to post. I have indexed column x for this example as a reading exam. 
Sub AddThreadedCommentToWorkbookOne()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SearchValue As String
Dim commentText As String
Dim cellRef As String
Dim resultCell As Range
' Set the workbook references
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("This is the address of the second workbook on sharepoint. It opens but the index match returns error 9")
' Set the comment text
SearchValue = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
commentText = "Reading Mock Exam Set " & vbNewLine & wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D6") & vbNewLine & wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D8") & vbNewLine & wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D10") & vbNewLine & wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D12")
' Perform the index match to get the cell reference
 cellRef = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("X3:X500"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SearchValue, wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A500"), 0))

' Attempt to find the cell reference in the first worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Set resultCell = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(cellRef)
On Error GoTo 0
' If the cell is not found in the first worksheet, find it in another worksheet
If resultCell Is Nothing Then
For Each ws2 In wb2.Sheets
Set resultCell = ws2.Range(cellRef)
If Not resultCell Is Nothing Then
Exit For
End If
Next ws2
End If
' If the cell is found, add the threaded comment
If Not resultCell Is Nothing Then
wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").AddCommentThreaded commentText
Else: MsgBox "Cell reference not found in Workbook Two."
End If
' Close the Workbook Two and save
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub


The current code creates the comment fine and it will open the workbook 2 file. I get an error code 9 when it tries to the cell ref.
My question is, what am I doing wrong with the index match? Is this the best way to achieve what I want?

Can’t be done? If I’m expecting the impossible, please let me know
